# Selected values in yii2

Tags: yii2

[image]

I am trying to add shipping cost for each country.whenever i am trying to save those all values it added multiple row in table.
  But How can i show all these selected values in my edit form in yii2?

Controller:

```
 $countrywiseshipping = new ProductCountrywiseshipping();

  $countryArr = [];
    foreach ($countrylist as $country) {

        $countryArr[$country->idCountry->id_country]['code'] = $country->idCountry->iso_code;
        $countryArr[$country->idCountry->id_country]['call_prefix'] = $country->idCountry->call_prefix;
        $countryArr[$country->idCountry->id_country]['name'] = $country->name;
    }
```

View:

```
   <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-xs-6" id="cntryDiv">
   <div class="row repeat-addcountry-part" id="subcntry1">
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="shipcountry">
        <label>Country</label>
            <div class="categry-select">    
                <div class="styled-select">                                                         
                <select class="countries2 form-control" data-country="US">
                    <?php foreach ($countryArr as $country_id => $country) {     ?>
                            <option id="country_<?php echo $country_id ?>" value="<?php echo $country_id ?>" data-code="<?php echo strtolower($country['code']) ?>" data-prefix="<?php echo $country['call_prefix'] ?>" data-image="images/blank.gif" data-imagecss="flag <?php echo strtolower($country['code']) ?>" data-title="<?php echo $country['name'] ?>"><?php echo $country['name'] ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                </select>
                </div>                                                      
            </div>                                                      
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" id="costs">
        <label>Cost</label>
        <div class="input-cost">
            <?php echo $form->field($countrywiseshipping, 'price[]')->textInput(['onblur'=>'assocC(this)'])->label(false) ?>                                                    
        </div>                                                      
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a href="#" class="del-contry-btn rmv-cntry">Del Country</a>
        </div>
        <label>(To offer free shipping to your customers just enter $0.00.)</label>                                                 
        </div>                                          
    </div>
```

Edit:

```
  $countrywiseshipping = ProductCountrywiseshipping::find()->where(['id_product' => $id_product])->all();
```

If i print the variable $countrywiseshipping it return all selected values.
But i want all selected country alongwith price in edit form. How is it possible?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "selected"? Are there unselected options in the dropdown fields?

Comment: Please add your update action and view code or clarify your given view and controller code used for update process?

Comment: How to show saved recods in dropdown(country) alongwith textbox(cost)?